# "Input encoding conversion not supported" Warning with vi

Tags: edit, vi, freebsd

When I try to open any file using vi editor, I get a warning saying:
**Input encoding conversion not supported;**. The OS that I have is FreeBSD10.
What am I missing on my machine that is causing this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the encoding of the file is not supported by vi(1). What's the file you are trying to open?

Comment: What is the output of `:set fileencoding inputencoding`?

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski I was opening a normal txt file

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol The output that I get is:

+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+
fileencoding="US-ASCII"
inputencoding="US-ASCII"

Press any key to continue [: to enter more ex commands]:

Comment: And locale -m gives only two charmaps, so basically the issue is charmaps being missed on the box.               



# locale -m
ISO8859-1
US-ASCII

Comment: Well, that's your problem. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix that.